# optimization - scipy minimize with contraints on returned values

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

I have a function for weekly revenue, which is function of few variables (say variables are spend on different days of week, sunday through saturday). Now, I need to find the values of the variables that maximizes the weekly revenue.

In addition to above, I also need to have a constraint on the `total return on spend`, for the week.

> Total return on spend = total revenue/ total spend.

> Total revenue = sum of revenue from all 7 days  (total spend = sum of spend on all 7 days. Note that spend on each day is a variable in optimization).

I am using scipy optimize.minimize for this task.

```
minimize(revenue_for_week, initial, bounds = bnds, method='L-BFGS-B', constraints = constr)
```

The 'bnds', 'constr' in above formulation, are nothing but constraints on the spend for different days of week (say sum of all spend variables value should be $100, and each variable should be within $5 and $25)

In addition to constraints on variables, how do I also include a constraint of the return on spend (total revenue/ total spend) ? Say my constraint is 1.2, i.e, for every $ of spend , I need to receive $1.2 as revenue.

Because the optimizer tries different combination of spend variables, for each  combination of spend (for each weekday), I will have different total revenue and so this `total return on spend` will be coming from the function to minimize ( `revenue_For_week` in above). How do I tell the minimize function, that one of the constraint is constraint on the return value.

I tried the following approach in the `revenue_for_Week` function,

```
if total_return>=1.2:  
   return -total_Revenue # revenue from the spend combination
else:
   return 10000   # This way minimize function will know the value is so large when the return is <1.2
```

but did not work (always returning 10000 , since for the given combinations roas is <1.2). The minimize function is also trying few different values of variables, all in very close neighborhood of the initial values chosen for the variables. In only 17 iterations or less, it returns success (example - Where first 16 doesn't satisfy the constraint on variables, that sum of all should = $100, but the  17 satisfy. All 17 have a return value of 10000, in the above example. All have 10000, since they don't satisfy the roas constraint.). I know for certain other combinations, the roas >1.2, but the minimize function stops as soon as the variable constraint satisfy (even though all revenue seen so far 10000, across all iterations)

I also tried, `method = 'SLSQP'` in minimize but result is the same as above.

Question 2 :

How to make to scipy optimize check different range of values than the initial. IF initial is at 0.24, scipy is checking all in the neighborhood of 0.24 like 0.24**4**5345**4**35 or 0.24**3**5345**5**35. I wanted to make it look at values like 0.18 or 0.20

Comment: Please show your complete invocation of minimize. It needs to be reproducible.

Comment: Also include your bounds and constraints.

Comment: Spend is not a noun. Perhaps you mean expenditure. Are your revenues fixed and your expenditures variable?

Comment: @Reinderien Thanks for the response. I solved my issue based on the one from this thread -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64169852/optimizing-input-where-output-has-constraints-in-python